# Bootstrap 3 Nav collapse css issue

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with my site at www.morvargh-sailing.co.uk. I am using Bootstrap 3 and normal css, not less etc.

It seems that either my media queries or custom css for the nav bar are not set up correctly and the main navbar is not being responsive.  I can click the three bar link but the drop downs are not styled correctly.

I am using wordpress as well so using the custom nav file to make bootstrap menus work.  Below is my php and css for the navbar.  Could anyone point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong. (N.B. My media queries are empty.)

PHP.

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"     data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="brand">
            <h1>Morvargh Sailing Project</h1></a><p>Using Sail Training to Inspire and Change Lives</p>
        </div>
        </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse pull-right">
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'false',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
```

And my CSS styling is...

```
    /* NAVIGATION ============================================================ */

.navbar-wrapper
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:10;
    margin-bottom:-70px
}

.navbar .navbar-inner
{

}

.navbar
{
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse
{
    height:64px!important;
}

.brand h1, .brand h1 a, .brand h1 a:hover
{
    margin-left: 26px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size:1.4EM;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.navbar-header p
{
    margin-left: 35px;
    color: #09f;
    font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
    font-size:26px;
    margin-top:-13px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}


.navbar-nav
{
    margin: 7.5px 10px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a
{
    height:58px;
    color: #fff!important;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover
{
    height: 58px;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #09F;
    background:url(../img/menu_arrow.png)center bottom repeat-x
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:active
{
    height:58px;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #09F;
    background:url(../img/menu_arrow.png)center bottom repeat-x
}


.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus
{
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #09F;
    background:url(../img/menu_arrow.png)center bottom repeat-x
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus
{
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

.dropdown-toggle
{
    height: 58px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu
{
    margin-top:3px;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-top:solid 2px #09F;
}

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu a
{
    color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus
{
    background-color:#09F;
}
```

Any help or pointers would really help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your collapsed menu has a scrollbar, then here's the offending rule:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse
{
    height:64px!important;
}
```

Try wrapping that in a media-query for min-width:768px.  Then it will only be applied when the full menu is displayed but will not be applied on the collapsed menu.

You can also change the floating there instead of using the utility class .pull-right so that the menu items will be floating left in the collapsed menu.

Comment: That's great thank you! In fact i've found if I take it out entirely it works. :-)